# Removing initials Regex 2 spaces

Tags: sql, regex

Hi I am trying to extract the surname from a list of initials and names
it is ok for one inital but 2 I just cant seem to get it right

```
SELECT NAMES, REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMES,'(\s.+$)') FROM PEOPLE
```

this gets me this top table. I have faffed about online for hours now trying to get to work with some online testers but just seems to break it. anyone help out with the right `'(\s.+$)'` ??

I tried this
`\s{2,}.+$` but no dice comes back with nothing :(
same result as below `\s.{2,}+$`

This is what I have

TABLE PEOPLE

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A Peat | Peat |
| D Jones | Jones |
| F Peat | Peat |
| D Jones | Jones |
| F D Peat | D Peat |
| D Jones | Jones |

What I am after......

TABLE PEOPLE

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A Peat | Peat |
| D Jones | Jones |
| F Peat | Peat |
| D Jones | Jones |
| F D Peat | Peat |
| D Jones | Jones |

hopefully the question is good enough but this box is not long enough for all my disasters I have tried :) `(\s.+$)`

Comment: Which DB type do you use?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT NAMES, REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMES,'(\S+)$') FROM PEOPLE
```

The `\S+` pattern will match one or more non-whitespace chars and `$` will make sure these chars are at the end of string.

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS!!
thank you. I see now. Im amazed i didnt accidentally do that :)   not wanting be a pain but if I make it    SELECT NAMES, REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMES,'(\S+)$') as SURNAME FROM PEOPLE  can i then Group by SURNAMES?                      thank you for your help xxxxx

Comment: @Ian Try adding `GROUP BY SURNAME`, but this is out of the current question scope already.

Comment: thank you sorted it I was being datf   SELECT NAMES, REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMES,'(\S+)$') as surname    then  group by REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMES,'(\S+)$')  and jobs a good one :)  thank you

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 SELECT names
 ,regexp_substr(names, '\\b(\\w+)$') last_name
 FROM people;
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this but the server returns (null)